# Type of dispatch result in redux toolik

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I'm using the base CRA-Redux template

```bash
npx create-react-app my-app --template redux-typescript
```

Full code can found [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/cra-template-redux-typescript/blob/master/template/src/features/counter/Counter.tsx)

What I need to do is to pass a dispatch result as callback to parent component. But I don't know which type should be the `dispatchResult`. Can you help me with this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is to use `ReturnType` hack

```
onClick: ({dispatchResult}: {
  dispatchResult: ReturnType<ReturnType<typeof incrementAsync>>;
}) => void;
```